# Random Sampling multiple Dataframes by Rows in a folder using R

Tags: r, dataframe, preprocessor

Sorry I'm very new to programming so I need all the help I can get.
I'm using R and I'm facing a task as follows:

I have a folder of 40 files in .csv. all of them have the same header and same amount (131) of columns (or features) but each having different rows (2000 to 10,000 rows).

Due to computational limits: I want to subset each file/data frame in the folder, say RANDOM sampling 300 rows from each data frame, and apply this random row sampling to all the files in the folder.

In the end, I want to combine all the sampled dataframes into one dataframe and write out a .csv file.

My ideas :

## --find folder path

`folder.path<-getwd()`

## read all csv files

`filenames <- list.files(folder.path, pattern = "*.csv", full.names = T)
suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(dplyr))
listdf <- lapply(filenames, read.csv)`

## here it screwed up, as I'm putting a "list" at a place expecting a data frame.

`listdf <- lapply(listdf, subset(sample_n(listdf, 300)))`

so I'm stuck, and obviously I haven't sorted out the header problems: I need to keep only one set of header for the final dataframe, and manual typing 131 column names is a little suicidal...

Thank you guys in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, sample the data:

```
 listdf <- lapply(listdf, FUN = function(i) sample_n(i, 300))
```

Then use an `rbind` inside `do.call` to bind all the data, note that this will only function as long as all the dataframes have the same number of columns, as well as the same column names:

```
 data <- do.call("rbind", listdf)
```

Comment: Hi David, thank you for the input. I think it worked. But where do I get the merged csv file? Can you help? I want to write the r binded dataframes into a new csv with the same column names. The file can be just named as new merged